# Return to RootController is crashing my app

Tags: iphone

My application is crashing, I think, in `RootController.m` and I don't know why. It occurs when I am in any view controller and I push the back button. It briefly returns to `RootController` and then it crashes. There is no messages on the console. I don't think it is the `ViewController` as I have tried more than one.

Here is the code.

```
    #import "confirmViewController.h"


    @implementation confirmViewController

    @synthesize lblStatus;
    @synthesize lblCardType;
    @synthesize lblCardNumber;
    @synthesize lblExpires;
    @synthesize lblAmount;
    @synthesize lblApproval;

    @synthesize strConfirmation;
    @synthesize strCardNumber;
    @synthesize strExpires;
    @synthesize strAmount;
    @synthesize strApproval;

/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //prepare confirmation, all that is needed is the first string      
    NSArray *strings = [strConfirmation componentsSeparatedByString: @","]; 
    NSString *strPreParsed = [strings objectAtIndex:0];

    //break out yes/no so we can set status
    //NSString *strYesNO = [strPreParsed substringToIndex:2];
    NSString *strYesOrNo = [strPreParsed substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(1, 1)];

    //save approval for later
    strApproval = strYesOrNo;

    //debug
        NSLog(@"strNo= %@",strYesOrNo);
        NSLog(@"strPreParsed= %@", strPreParsed);


    if([strYesOrNo compare:@"Y"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblStatus.text = @"Approved";
        lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    if([strYesOrNo compare:@"N"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblStatus.text = @"Declined";
        lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if([strYesOrNo compare:@"U"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblStatus.text = @"Try Again";
        lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    //set card type
    if([lblCardNumber.text compare:@"4"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblCardType.text = @"Visa";
    }

    if([lblCardNumber.text compare:@"5"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblCardType.text = @"Master";
    }

    if([lblCardNumber.text compare:@"6"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        lblCardType.text = @"Discover";
    }



    //set cardnumber
    lblCardNumber.text = strCardNumber;

    //set expires
    lblExpires.text = strExpires;

    //set amount
    lblAmount.text = strAmount;

    //set approval string
    lblApproval.text = strPreParsed;


}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    //show signature
    sigCaptureViewController *yetAnotherViewController = [[sigCaptureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sigCaptureView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yetAnotherViewController animated:YES];
    [yetAnotherViewController release];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

    [lblCardType dealloc];
    [lblCardNumber dealloc];
    [lblExpires dealloc];
    [lblAmount dealloc];
    [lblApproval dealloc];
    [lblStatus dealloc];

    [strConfirmation dealloc];
    [strCardNumber dealloc];
    [strExpires dealloc];
    [strAmount dealloc];
    [strApproval dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely releasing something twice in your `SalesViewController`, it's crashing when that object's dealloc is getting called and doing the 2nd release.

You didn't include that contorller's code, either look for it yourself or paste it here and I'll help you spot it :)

Here's a scenario you should look for:

```
// somewhere within your sales controller
- (void)someWhere {
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray array];
    self.myArray = arr;
    [arr release]; // notice how arr wasn't initialized with an init
    // so no release is required
    // but since your myArray is a @property(retain) it won't crash here 
    // because the property did a retain
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myArray relase]; // this does the 2nd release and BOOM
}
```

EDIT after your target view controller was pasted:

It might be because you forgot to set one of the properties you're releasing in the dealloc. Try setting a breakpoints in your dealloc and see if one of the properties is actually null before releasing it, if so, that's why it crashes.

EDIT #2, are you sure you want to be calling `[lblSometing dealloc]` instead of `[lblSomething release]`?

Comment: It happens with another view controller as well. That one is a little shorter so I will paste in below. Any help appreciated.